# in laravel view I want the content of the url and not the url itself

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to show the content instead of the url in my view. How can I use Laravel to make this work?

At the moment, in my Laravel view I have:

```
<a href="{!! route('plaats.text', ['plaats' => $plaatsje]) !!}">Link</a>
<p>{!! route('plaats.text', ['plaats' => $plaatsje]) !!}</p>
<p>{!! action('TablesController@text', ['plaats' => $plaatsje]) !!}</p>
```

The first creates a link with a working active url, the second and third a death link: "http://mysecondsite.dev/koop/text/plaats/capelle-aan-den-ijssel".

Following the link itself (in all cases) returns the expected content of the url (So, my routing seems to be ok). But neither returns the underlying content.

regards
Peter

Comment: can you explain better? what do you mean by "content of url" ? this links is the content of the url

Comment: when I follow this link in my development environment It shows text. This text I would like to have in my view, not the url itself.

Comment: so instead of showing links, put the html you want. if you want to include another view in your view than use blade @include

Comment: you can also make an Ajax call, means that the page content will be shown in side another page, if you do not know how to do that let me know, I have tried similar problem like your question previously

Comment: You need to use `file_get_contents` to fetch the content of the page, store it in a variable and then echo it out in your view.

Comment: @amir that would work in case of static html, but I have to use a second method of the same controller.

Comment: What you're trying to do is bad practice in the sense that it goes against all the beauty of an MVC framework :) Try and get the data on the controller layer and then pass that to your view. If you're re-using data / views in views you might want to consider the use of @include() :)

Comment: There might be some miscommunication here: the controller method fetches some data from an external api with the help of the casinelli/laravel-wikipedia package, that's what i am referring to. I am not using file_get_contents for fetching content but added an object to the return view which is being read out in the blade. I think this complies with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is blade [service injection](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#service-injection)

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to inject logic into views.

What you probably should do is do the operations before the view, and then pass the results (contents) to the view and echo them